# Separating numbers to different strings or an array

Tags: php, arrays, numbers

I'm using Laravel 4 to count my database entries and I need to split each number to a different string or an array.

```
$users = DB::table('users')->count();
```

The result is for example 349, and I need to get:

```
$string1 = 0;
$string2 = 0;
$string3 = 3;
$string4 = 4;
$string5 = 9;
```

or an array

```
$string[0] = 0;
$string[1] = 0;
$string[2] = 3;
....
```

I specifically need 5 numbers, even if the `count();` result is 349 I need to add 0 and 0 before it, or if I get 1234 - one zero needs to be before it because I need 5 numbers.

What do I need to use to get wanted results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using with `str_split` and `str_pad`

```
$users = DB::table('users')->count();

$array = str_split(str_pad($users, 5 , 0, STR_PAD_LEFT));
```

#### Output of Array

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => string '4' (length=1)
  4 => string '9' (length=1)
```

Comment: Since some web hosting providers disable sprintf for security reasons I will choose your answer. Thank You!

Comment: Is ````str_split```` necessary? You can treat strings as an array of characters anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$users=349;
$values=str_split(sprintf('%05d', $users));
print_r($values);
?>
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/I9by6YjM)**

Answer (score 1):

As commented very early:

You can use `sprintf`:

```
$num = 349;
$string = str_split(sprintf('%05d', $num));
print_r($string);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 9
)
```

### [**Live demo!**](https://eval.in/46229)